# Optimize SQL queries in php file

Tags: php, sql

I wrote PHP script to auto-update offers from provider API in my database. Unfortunately, by performing the following queries in the foreach loop (following the API records), the load is at 99% of the CPU. The script must be activated in cron every 10-15 minutes, but with this load the server is weak. How could I optimize it for more efficient work?

```
<?php

    include "config.php";

    function checkDevice($device) {

        if($device == "Android" || $device == "iOS" || $device == "iPhone" || $device == "iPad") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function countUserPayout($providerPayout) {

        $summary = ($providerPayout * 100) / 2;
        return ceil($summary);

    }

    function getOgAds() {

        $response = file_get_contents("link");
        $result = json_decode($response, true);

        return $result["offers"];

    }

    function getAdGate() {

        $response = file_get_contents("link");
        $result = json_decode($response, true);

        return $result["data"];

    }

    function checkOgAdsDevice($devices) {

        $devicesArray = explode(",", $devices);

        foreach($devicesArray as $device) {

            if($device == "iPhone" || $device == "iPad" || $device == "Android") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

    function detectDesktop($category) {

        $categories = explode(",", $category);
        $exists = array_search("Desktop", $categories);

        if($exists) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function createCountries($object) {

        foreach($object as $country) {

            $countries[] = $country;

        }

        if(isset($countries)) {
            return $countries;
        }

    }

    function createOfferWall() {

        $offerWall = [];

        foreach(getOgAds() as $offer) {

            if(checkOgAdsDevice($offer["device"]) && detectDesktop($offer["device"]) == false) {

                $offerWall[] = array(

                                    "offer_id" => $offer["offerid"],
                                    "name" => $offer["name_short"],
                                    "requirements" => $offer["adcopy"],
                                    "category" => $offer["device"],
                                    "provider_payout" => $offer["payout"], 
                                    "payout" => countUserPayout($offer["payout"]),
                                    "epc" => $offer["epc"],
                                    "icon" => $offer["picture"],
                                    "anchor" => $offer["link"],
                                    "countries" => (array)$offer["country"],
                                    "provider" => "ogads"

                                );

            } else {

                continue;

            }

        }

        foreach(getAdGate() as $offer) {

            if(checkDevice($offer["categories"][0])) {

                $offerWall[] = array(

                                    "offer_id" => $offer["id"], 
                                    "name" => $offer["adgate_rewards"]["anchor"],
                                    "requirements" => $offer["requirements"], 
                                    "category" => $offer["categories"][0],
                                    "provider_payout" => $offer["payout"],
                                    "payout" => countUserPayout($offer["payout"]),
                                    "epc" => $offer["epc"], 
                                    "icon" => $offer["creatives"]["icon"], 
                                    "anchor" => $offer["click_url"],
                                    "countries" => createCountries($offer["countries"]),
                                    "provider" => "adgate"

                                    );

            } else {

                continue;

            }

        }

        return $offerWall;

    }

    function createIdWall($dbh) {

        $offerWall = createOfferWall();

        foreach($offerWall as $offer) {

            $idWall[$offer["offer_id"]] = $offer["offer_id"];

        }

        return $idWall;

    }

    function setCountries($dbh, $countries, $offer) {

        if(isset($countries)) {
            foreach($countries as $country) {

                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table`(`aaa`,`xxx`,`yyy`) VALUES(NULL, :country, :oid)");
                    $stmt->bindParam(":country", $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(":oid", $offer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->execute();

            }
        }

    }

    function checkOfferExists($dbh, $providerId) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(`id`) as `exists` FROM `table` WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result["exists"] == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function getOfferInfo($dbh, $providerId) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;

    }

    function compareOffers($dbh, $providerId, $offer) {

        $dbOffer = getOfferInfo($dbh, $providerId);

        if($dbOffer["provider_payout"] != $offer["provider_payout"] || $dbOffer["anchor"] != $offer["anchor"] || $dbOffer["offer_name"] != $offer["name"] || $dbOffer["category"] != $offer["category"] || $dbOffer["icon"] != $offer["icon"] || $dbOffer["requirements"] != $offer["requirements"]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function getDbOffers($dbh) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `provider_id` FROM `table`");
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;

    }

    function activateOffer($dbh, $providerId) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    function disableOffer($dbh, $providerId) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `active` = 0 WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    function updateOffer($dbh, $providerId, $offer) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET 
                              `aaa` = :payout,
                              `bbb = :points,
                              `ccc` = :anchor,
                              `ddd` = :name,
                              `eee` = :category,
                              `fff` = :icon,
                              `ggg` = :requirements
                              WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");

        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":payout", $offer["provider_payout"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":points", $offer["payout"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":anchor", $offer["anchor"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $offer["name"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":category", $offer["category"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":icon", $offer["icon"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":requirements", $offer["requirements"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

    }

    function addOffer($dbh, $offer) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc, `ddd`, `eee`, `fff`, `ggg`, `hhh`, `jjj`, `kkk`, `lll`, `zzz`, `xxx`) VALUES (NULL, :requirements, :points, :providerId, :icon, :epc, :ownPayout, :anchor, :category, :name, 1, 0, :provider);");
        $stmt->bindParam(":requirements", $offer["requirements"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":points", $offer["payout"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $offer["offer_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":icon", $offer["icon"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":epc", $offer["epc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ownPayout", $offer["provider_payout"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":anchor", $offer["anchor"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":category", $offer["category"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $offer["name"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":provider", $offer["provider"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        setCountries($dbh, $offer["countries"], $offer["offer_id"]);

    }

    function checkStatus($dbh, $providerId) {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `active` FROM `table` WHERE `provider_id` = :providerId");
        $stmt->bindParam(":providerId", $providerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result["active"] == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function followOffers($dbh) {

        foreach(createOfferWall() as $offer) {

            if(checkOfferExists($dbh, $offer["offer_id"])) {

                if(compareOffers($dbh, $offer["offer_id"], $offer)) {

                    updateOffer($dbh, $offer["offer_id"], $offer);

                } else {

                    continue;

                }

            } else {

                addOffer($dbh, $offer);

            }

        }

    }

    function findRevokeOffers($dbh) {

        $idWall = array_flip(createIdWall($dbh));

        foreach(getDbOffers($dbh) as $dbOffer) {

            $providerId = $dbOffer["provider_id"];

            if(isset($idWall[$providerId])) {

                continue;

            } else {

                if(checkStatus($dbh, $providerId)) {

                    disableOffer($dbh, $providerId);

                } else {

                    continue;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    function getCurrentTime() {

        $currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        return $currentTime;

    }

    echo "// START [".getCurrentTime()."]" .PHP_EOL;

    followOffers($dbh);
    findRevokeOffers($dbh);

    echo "// END" .PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Comment: Please show all the code, including the `foreach` loop. And the updates. You only show `SELECT`s.

Comment: @BartFriederichs okay, wait a second

Comment: @BartFriederichs done

Comment: Please cache your prepared statements. Dont re-prepare every time. Just store the prepared statements in a variable, then call bind param on that every time. Saves a bit of overhead and execution cycles.

Comment: You do a lot in your PHP code. Optimising this isn't trivial. Because the code is working, I advise you to move the question to codereview.stackexchange.com